# How can I remove some text from a PDF in Foxit PDF Editor, when the text isn't recognized as text by Foxit PDF Editor?

Tags: windows, pdf

For example, I would like to remove "California" in the screenshot below:

[image]

"California"  isn't recognized as text by Foxit PDF Editor (I tried the "Edit Text", as shown in the screenshot).

Comment: Try to Edit the file which will make text in images editable. That certainly works in Adobe Acrobat.   I am not certain about Foxit.  It may not be possible in the a Reader Version.

Comment: Are you sure it's text in the first place, or is it an image? If that's a scanned doc, it is an image and you need to OCR it to edit text.

Comment: If image it must be converted to text (as I noted above) by the OCR component in something like Acrobat.  That works and I have used it.

Comment: @John Thanks, I tried the "Edit Text" feature.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thanks, California isn't recognized as text by Foxit OCR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Edit Object -> Shape:

[image]

But save before trying that:

[image]

Comment: Maybe try a 30 day trial of Adobe Acrobat DC to see if Adobe will do the job.

Comment: @John thanks, Foxit didn't crash on second try. Adobe Acrobat DC probably would work indeed.